# Elastic IP AWS EC2 Blocked Web Scraping

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip

I scraped a website too frequently and I think got blocked by the website.
Scraping is allowed for the website but I think my loop was missing a sys.sleep() function (I code in R).

I am using R on an RStudio IDE on a EC2 instance from AWS.
I tried changing the elastic IP hoping it would remove the ban but it did not.

Do you know how I can change the associated IP to my EC2 instance?

Thanks a lot.

M

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change outgoing IP address of EC2 instance which access internet via Internet Gateway you can do it in 2 ways:

1. If you have attached EIP to EC2 you can create new EIP and replace the old one
2. If you don't have attached EIP you can just stop and start your EC2 instance as every stop/start combination in EC2 cause that your EC2 is launched in new location in datacenter what effectively gives you new public IP address

Comment: Thanks. I tried both of the solution before and I was still blocked right after  changing the EIP. But 10 minutes after was not blocked anymore. Not sure if there is a delay to be expected? Would there be a way to change EIP dynamically from the R script?

Comment: Stopping and then starting an EC2 instance "might" change the public IP address. After a quick stop/start cycle the public IP is often the same. The private IP will NOT change. Only "classic" instances change the private IP address. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Stop_Start.html

Comment: Thank you @JohnHanley - I corrected my answer regarding private IP. But I can't agree with public address as usually I'm receiving new one in stop/start procedure.